# Can a monitor get damaged due to rotating?

Tags: display

Can a particular monitor(-type) get damaged when it gets rotated while it's powered on?

*(like a screen-holder such as [this](http://www.kontorsvaror.se/8685-9375-large/multibrackets-m-vesa-desktopmount-iii-dubbel-svart.jpg) allows)*

Comment: If you flex it enough, anything can break.

Comment: @techie007 Well, I'm talking about normal rotating - carefully of course.

Comment: Since monitors are solid-state, their orientation shouldn't affect their performance.  Did you actually have this problem, or are you just wondering?

Comment: @techie007 Just ensuring before ordering :-).

Comment: Pay special attention to connections. I'd say the DVI cables and connectors will receive most stress during rotation if you're not careful, and are first to give if you rotate your monitors often (often = several times a day). And of course it doesn't matter if your monitor is on or off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any movement can cause damage especially if it is often and especially with older monitors.

However, in most cases, it will be safe to rotate the monitor. I would not anticipate any problems.

Answer (score 2):

There are generally no moving parts in a monitor that you need to worry about.. Many actually come with built in rotating stands and if connected by DVI will tell the computer to change the orientation of the screen automatically.

Comment: Great! Hmm, did I misunderstand you or do you mean that the DVI-cable detects if my monitor is in landscape / portrait?

Comment: Within the monitor and the stand there is a sensor - this info can only be passed up a digital cable, not VGA

Comment: Not every monitor has this sensor, right?

Comment: @ck: Not true; VGA also has 4 ["DDC"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) pins.

Comment: @Zar: They're fairly rare, I think they're exclusive to monitors which are shipped with a pivot stand included. E.g. Samsung SyncMaster S24A650S

Comment: @MSalters Guessed that too, quite sad if you ask me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah only a few monitors support it. You can however set up hotkeys in ATI Catalyst and the Nvidia equivalent to allow you to rotate the screen quickly.

Answer (score 2):

LCD monitors can be safely rotated while on with no problems.  I've used one rotated as part of an arcade cabinet for a few years now with no issues, many users at my old place of business also used rotated monitors at the time, and they weren't even gentle with them in the least.